# Is it possible to have an absolute zero CPU utilization?

Tags: cpu, hardware, cpu-usage, zabbix

An Idle server(unix, windows), with at least a chef client and a Zabbix agent running on them, can have the absolute zero CPU utilization, or it is always using, for example, at least 0.001%?

Comment: You mean with the computer switched on?

Comment: What are you *actually seeking to prove here*? Some of your comments look like you're seeking an iron-clad guarantee of some kind. We're not going to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

To achive **Zero** cpu utilization you need to Shut it down.

Following are the ways:

- Manually click on the shut down(on windows).
- You can create a batch file for the same.
- Pull the power cable out.(*Not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Most CPUs have a Halt instruction, or its moral equivalent. When the Halt instruction is reached, the CPU will stop executing its normal, Fetch-Decode-Execute loop (or moral equivalent).

The only thing that can bring the CPU out of this state is the delivery of an external interrupt (from some other piece of hardware), which will cause the CPU to perform its normal interrupt processing. What it does after that is up to the operating system.

---

As an example, a system may arrange for its network cards to cause interrupts and then Halt. Most, modern, everyday OSes will not do this since they have plenty of background tasks that they can schedule when the CPU would otherwise be idle.

Comment: or a timer tick, or a watchdog etc. That said most computers do actually spend the vast majority of their time halted.

Comment: But if I have at least an Zabbix agent running on my server, if it sends the cpu utilization metric equals to 0.0, my question is if this is correct/possible or there is a problem over there

Comment: @Mgetz - which are examples of external interrupts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true. Nitpicker's corner: Although in most cases those are now part of the CPU silicon today.

Comment: @dpolicastro depends on your expected load. If you have a CPU at zero utilization I would say you have a candidate for something that needs to be dockerized/containerized/VM'd.

Comment: @dpolicastro - it's unclear what you're actually looking for here. The answer to "is this possible" is yes. The answer to "is this possible using <lots of information not included in the question>" is still yes, but to assess the likelihood we need specifics.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm asking if the CPU utilization of a running server can be 0%, regarding the server runs at least a chef client and a Zabbix agent, or it might be an error from the Zabbix agent.

Comment: @dpolicastro - do you not think then that a much better question would involve a [mcve] involving a Zabbix agent (whatever that is) and whether it could legitimately record zero percent usage? Rather than asking random questions that can apply to all computer systems everywhere?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah much better

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the definition of CPU utilization.

At the CPU level, utilization can't be zero, unless the computer is off. Which is intuitive of course. Some process is always running, that should constitute good architecture.

Normally though, at the OS level, CPU utilization is calculated by the OS and its probable that each OS will have its own implementation of the calculation algorithm.

There are a certain set of tasks known as idle tasks, which run when there are no non-idle processes to run. In linux boot, the idle task comes under **process 0**.

Utilization for a period of time, is the percentage of time non-idle processes were run. For 10ms, if the CPU was idle for 5ms, utilization is 50%.

Simply put, 0% utilization means the CPU is running, but its just waiting for other tasks to be assigned, while running default idle tasks. It is also possible for some minor, non-idle tasks to be running, at something like 0.0001% utilization, which gets rounded off to zero.

Comment: [HLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction))? CPU utilization *can* be zero.

Comment: agree with hasris on this, cpu utilization is a bit of an illusion, and very much defined by the specific operating system or implementation.  the os is still cranking away getting interrupts running code, computing the utilization of what that operating system's or implementation defined definition of utilization is,  the code doing the math as well as some percentage of other code is not measured, by definition.  So this is a too broad question as it doesnt talk about the specific operating system, version, etc, on the specific hardware, etc...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think the idle_task in some OSes are a repeated loop of HLT instructions. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU). This leads me to believe that even after HLT, there's some process in there waiting for an interrupt.